# Concatenate separated char** elements in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following situation:

An initial `char* original_string = "@person Hello person! Welcome to the chat!";`

I needed to take the `"@person"` part so I have a split function that will take the `original_string` and split it by spaces.
Basically `char** split_original_string = split_string(original_string, " ");` will return:

```
    split_original_string[0] = "@person";
    split_original_string[1] = "Hello";
    split_original_string[2] = "person!";
    split_original_string[3] = "Welcome ";
    split_original_string[4] = "to";
    split_original_string[5] = "the";
    split_original_string[6] = "chat!";
```

Since now I have the `@person` I am happy! But I realised that the message should be the rest of the `original_string` meaning `"Hello person! Welcome to the chat!"`.

I have tried to use something like

```
char* message = malloc(256); // 256 is just for testing purposes
strncpy(message , original_string + strlen(split_original_string[0]), strlen(original_string ));
```

But it resulted of empty `char*` because apparently when passing the `original_string` to the `split_original_string` function it changed and the its length was equal to the length of the `split_original_string[0]`.

My question is: **Is there a way to concatenate the rest of the `char**` elements in a single `char*` using a `for` loop or any other loop?**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably need to use `strtok`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky you mean that for the splitting?

Comment: @JohnRambo I wonder how you are getting "chat"; instead of "chat!";

Comment: Yes, that's a start. Copy the string before using `strtok`because you can't use `strtok` on a string literal.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry typo...i have edit it! Thanks!

Comment: Beware! You declared `original_string` as a `char *` but it actually points to a litteral string which is a **`const`** `char *`. As `strtok` modifies the string, using it over a const object invokes Undefined Behaviour. If you want to process const strings you'd better use `str[c]spn` that do almost the same job as `strtok` do but never change the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a lightweight program to archive that. No external functions

```
char *mySpecialstrcat(char *str, const char *src, int appendSpace)
{
    while(*str++ = *src++);
    if(appendSpace) *(str - 1) = ' ';
    *str = 0;
    return str;
}

char *combine(char *buff, char **strings)
{
    char *end = buff;
    while(*strings)
    {
        end = mySpecialstrcat(end, *strings, strings[1] != NULL);
        strings++;
    }
    return buff;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *buff = malloc(256);
    char *split_original_string[8];
    split_original_string[0] = "@person";
    split_original_string[1] = "Hello";
    split_original_string[2] = "person!";
    split_original_string[3] = "Welcome ";
    split_original_string[4] = "to";
    split_original_string[5] = "the";
    split_original_string[6] = "chat!";
    split_original_string[7] = NULL;


    printf("%s\n", combine(buff, split_original_string));
    free(buff);
}
```